# LINQ to SQL Left Join over Left Join c#

Tags: c#, join, linq-to-sql, left-join

I am trying to perform left join over an existing left join as this is a lookup table.

something like:

```
(from m in maintablerepository.AsQueryable()
join st1 in subtable1repository.AsQuerable on 
m.id = s1.id into grps1
from s in grps1.DefaultIfEmpty()
join lt1 in lookuptablerepository.AsQuerable on 
s.lkpid = lt1.id into grplt1
from lkp in grplt1.DefaultIfEmpty()

select new {

prop1 = m.prop1,
prop2 = s.prop2,
prop3 = lkp.prop3

}).ToList();
```

The issue is that this query runs fine when I remove the left join on the lookup table, though there is not matching value in sub table.

However putting this back in place results in "Object reference not set" error.

I have even tried the following, but no go:

```
(from m in maintablerepository.AsQueryable()
join st1 in subtable1repository.AsQuerable on 
m.id = s1.id into grps1
from s in grps1.DefaultIfEmpty()
join lt1 in lookuptablerepository.AsQuerable on 
s.lkpid = lt1.id into grplt1
from lkp in grplt1.DefaultIfEmpty()
where s!=null && lkp!=null
select new {

prop1 = m.prop1,
prop2 = (s==null)?string.Empty:s.prop2,
prop3 = (lkp==null)?string.Empty:lkp.prop3

}).ToList();
```

If the first left join results in a null, how does one do another join on it?

Comment: I'm sure that this can be done, however, why not break it into two or more late bound queries?  The speed would be the same and the code would be much more readable.

Comment: Did you mean querying till sub table 1 in the first query and then joining lookup table in another query and finally doing a tolist to generate the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with s.lkpid = lt1.id with s being null. Try placing the s != null like the the one below

```html
(from m in maintablerepository.AsQueryable()
join st1 in subtable1repository.AsQuerable on 
m.id = s1.id into grps1
from s in grps1.DefaultIfEmpty()
where s!=null
join lt1 in lookuptablerepository.AsQuerable on 
s.lkpid = lt1.id into grplt1
from lkp in grplt1.DefaultIfEmpty()
where lkp!=null
select new {

prop1 = m.prop1,
prop2 = (s==null)?string.Empty:s.prop2,
prop3 = (lkp==null)?string.Empty:lkp.prop3

}).ToList();
```

*Please mark the post as answered if it helped you*

Comment: Amazing!...a where clause in between joins and it solved the issue for me!